# Visual Studio 2015 and HTML Design View

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I'm currently working on a project where I have to create an Application using SQL in Visual Studio 2015 (UWP).

The problem is , that Microsoft hasn't published any guide or tutorials for VS 2015 and SQL, as far as I know. There are some guides for previous Visual Studio but I always get to a point where something is missing or not the same.

I manage somehow  to connect the SQL database to my project (still don't know if it is the correct way) but my biggest problem is that I can't find any C# code to connect the SQL table to my application.

Even when I find some code, it is not working because some libraries are missing or it is not well explained (such as `System.Data.SqlClient`). I read that I can use SQLite with Entity Framework but I don't know how or if it is possible.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you have been searching for 2 weeks for a tutorial with C# and databases and have found absolutely nothing.

Comment: 996,000 google hits for "C# database" on StackOverflow.com alone. Add more terms to get more specific info...and dont ignore the *questions* just because they are asking something doesnt mean *you* cant learn from it.

Comment: VS 2015 Community Edition really doesn't offer existing DB with CodeFirst EF7 ;(. Yes it is possible to do it manually.

Comment: To use SQLite with Entity Framework on Universal Windows Platform, you can refer to [Getting Started on Universal Windows Platform](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's absolutely normal, that you can't find any information about how to connect SQL Server and UWP application. Because.. there is no way to do it directly. If you want to connect your UWP app with SQL Server you need to create REST web service.
But you can use local SQLite database. There are different ways how to do it and EF is not required (but if you wish you can use it). For example you can use this tutorial:
[SQLite Wrapper for Windows 10 UWP applications](http://progrunning.net/sqlite-wrapper-for-windows-10-uwp-applications/)